# Should I add the Rails 4 bin/ directory to git?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4

After I upgraded to Rails 4, the bin/ directory appeared. Do I need to commit this to git, or should I leave it for bundler to regenerate on the server?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4) you should add it.

> This will generate a bin directory in the root of your application. Make sure that it is not in your .gitignore file, and check this directory and its contents into git.

Comment: Thanks. Is this specific to Heroku, or does it apply to every host (I'm using Engine Yard)?

Comment: I dont know if this helps, but i personally had a problem in the bin directory with the first line (#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe) where i had to remove the .exe to properly run on Heroku.
And you need to commit it to git.

Answer (score 17):

Here is the message from Rails w.r.t bin/ directory:

> In Rails 4, your app's bin/ directory contains executables that are
>   versioned like any other source code, rather than stubs that are
>   generated on demand.  Here's how to upgrade:

```
bundle config --delete bin    # Turn off Bundler's stub generator
rake rails:update:bin         # Use the new Rails 4 executables
git add bin                   # Add bin/ to source control
```

You may need to remove bin/ from your .gitignore as well.